# Determine which element triggered OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview

I have got a listview with 2 textviews inside it. I have set up my OnItemClickListener which works fine. However, I was wondering how to determine whether the OnItemClickListener was triggered by TextView01 or TextView02?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="5px"
 android:paddingTop="5px" android:paddingLeft="5px">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
 android:background="@drawable/bg" android:textColor="#FFFF00"
 android:text="hi"></TextView>
 <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02" android:id="@+id/TextView02"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:textColor="#0099CC"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>`

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
 
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onitemClickListener` is not triggered by click on textview. `onItemClickLister()` is a callback listener for listview; it is called when user click on list view.

To get click event on textview add clicklistener to textview. You will get its callback in `OnclickListener(view v)`.

Comment: Amazing, just wanted i needed to know. Thanks